# Word formation of fold?

Tags: word-formation

I saw this sentence this morning and I don't know which word I should put

> ... world's worst ________ environmental disaster. **(fold)**

I know one form of **fold** is **folding** but it seems not suitable in this sentence. What is the correct word to fill the gap? Thank you

Comment: Hope someone help me

Comment: +1 But have voted to send this to ELL stack exchange! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **unfolding**.

> **unfold** *verb*
>   no object (of events or information) gradually develop or be revealed.
>   ‘there was a fascinating scene unfolding before me’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unfold)

The "... world's worst unfolding environmental disaster" would be one that was happening at the time.